# Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found

Tags: android, windows, react-native, adb, genymotion

I'm trying to run my React Native application on Genymotion but, I keep getting this warning:

```
Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found
```

I've just installed Windows 11. Solved the same problem once when I was using Windows 10 but now, can't remember how.
Could anybody help me please?

I tried to add the adb's path to Environment Variables but, it didn't work out.

Comment: Genymotion included an own adb version which conflicts with the one installed from Android SDK. I recommend you to set adb path of the Android SDK in Genymotion ADB settings (-> ADB -> Use custom Android SDK tools).

Comment: I've already done the same but, it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- I put my android sdk files in this path (it's important to locate them in C):
  C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.
- I searched for "Edit the system environment variables" on my windows
- On "Advanced" topic, I clicked on "Environment Variables..."
- Then I clicked on "New" under "System variables" in "Environment Variables" and added my ADB directory to it:

Variable name: Path

Variable value: C:\Users\hosei\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools